# How to show random featured products (woocommerce) in a WP custom loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, wordpress-featured-image

I am trying to have a custom loop in Wordpress for Woocommerce products. I want to show a random featured product in the loop. But for some reason it doesn't get my arguments right and picks a random product from all products available.

This the code i'm using at moment. It does show a random product, but it ignores the featured part of the code.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'orderby'          => 'rand',
    'post_type'        => 'product',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'key'     => '_featured',
        'value'   => 'yes'
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    </a>
</li>

<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Can someone lead me into the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just come across this,

Its not directly for your issue, but could be the base of it.

It seems featured items are no longer stored as meta:

```
    $meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'featured',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );

$query_args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
    'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
);`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the solution. It's working now!
I've added 'orderby' => 'rand' to the $query_args so it's show one of the featured products at random.

Comment: Works for woocommerce 3.x - it would be nice to have function for featured products like: 'wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()'

Answer (score 2):

Featured Products Loop in WooCommerce 3

```
<ul class="products">
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                    'field'    => 'name',
                    'terms'    => 'featured',
                ),
            ),
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your key value array is too far up in the expected array hierarchy, try this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'orderby'          => 'rand',
    'post_type'        => 'product',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_featured',
            'value'   => 'yes',
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work. I tried the other way around too by placing the array one level up instead of one level down the array. That did not work either. Tried the argument 'meta_key' => '_featured' as well. did also not work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Try this ! Works for me

```
<?php
         $featured_query = new WP_Query( array(
             'tax_query' => array(
                     array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                     'field'    => 'name',
                     'terms'    => 'featured',
                     'operator' => 'IN'
                 ),
          ),
     ) );
?>
```